# Linux (Xubuntu,ubuntu,kubuntu) install problem!

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm try to install XUbuntu 10.10 (AMD64) on a Pc, when I set the language, and press Enter on "Try XUbuntu without installing", appears the Xubuntu logos and remain fixed for many hours without giving error... same problem with Ubuntu and Kubuntu.

I try to set **acpi=off** and **noapic** but i don't resolved the problem... 
You have any idea to resolving the problem?? 
thanks!!

Comment: Also, nowhere near enough details on what the hardware configuration is.

Comment: What is the make and model of said PC? As stated we need more information to hep you.

Comment: What make is it and How old?

Comment: What procceser do you have?

Answer (score 3):

You attempt to remove certain parameters by hitting 'e' for edit. They sometimes vary but removing "quiet", "nosplash" etc should show you more information and possibly an error message.